# The Flat Function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I  have to write an essay on the flat function

$$\text{flat}(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & \text{for } x \ne 0 \\
  0 & \text{for } x = 0
  \end{cases}$$

and I want to prove that the Maclauren series of flat does not converge to flat.

Can anyone help me with this?

http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~fthulin/essay3math.pdf
This is what my professor wrote about it... But I don't understand it...

Comment: Play around with the first couple of derivatives of the function. You should spot a pattern which you can prove using induction.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh alright let me try that, thanks!

Comment: If you get stuck, I'll try to elaborate more on the hint.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly written in the file you linked that the "Proposition" follows from the definition of the Maclaurin series (and Lemma 2).

It is shown in Lemma 2 that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$. (For simplicity I denote $f(x)=\textrm{flat}(x)$.) By the definition of the Maclaurin series of $f$ at $x=0$, the series is zero because all the its coefficits are zero. But $f$ is not zero for all $x\neq 0$. So they cannot be equal.